# flask jquery form validation redundancy

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I'm writing a web app with flask. But mixing web app with REST + jQuery is causing a bit confusion for me. So I have a page with a form prepared in flask:

```
class TestForm(Form):
    start_date = DateField('Start Date:')
    end_date = DateField('End Date:')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Normally this form will be validated in a view function and handled. But in this case, I've actually used jquery to do the form submission because of the availability of the REST API:

```
$("#new_cmp").bind('click', function() {
  alert('Posting...')
  $.post("http://localhost:7000/api/v1.0/cmp",
    {
      startdate: $("#start_date").val(),
      enddate: $("#end_date").val(),
    },
    function(data, status) {
      alert(status);
    }, "json");
  return false;
}
```

So all the validation stuff Flask does is gone. I'm starting to think this is not a good idea. What's the best way to use Ajax together with Flask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is up to you how are going to use AJAX with Flask. Flask's documentation give some ideas about [AJAX usage](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/), but you should take into account some things:

- AJAX is client-side technology, so you should use it only for client-side data representation;
- your server-side should be developed with the idea that server and only server is responsible for checking and processing data.

As for the validation, I use for my pet project [WTF Forms](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms), that provides tools for form creating and validation. For those cases, where I don't need form submission, I'm sending JSON response from the server, that will display required data to the client. You can find some ideas in this [post](http://chernetky.blogspot.com/2015/06/processing-flashed-messages-for.html).